# My WPF application is not taking snapshot using LibVLC library

Tags: wpf, vlc, libvlc, .net-core-3.1

I'm taking snapshot using `LibVLC` library.

I'm using following code to save `VlcVideoSourceProvider`

```
public Dictionary<string, VlcVideoSourceProvider> sourceProvider;
```

Then using following code to create and playing player in WPF application:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
{
  var localSourceProvider = sourceProvider[CameraNumber];
  if (localSourceProvider.MediaPlayer == null)
  {
     var currentAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
     var currentDirectory = new FileInfo(currentAssembly.Location).DirectoryName;
     var libDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "libvlc", IntPtr.Size == 4 ? "win-x86" : "win-x64"));
     localSourceProvider.CreatePlayer(libDirectory);
     localSourceProvider.MediaPlayer.Audio.Volume = 0;
     
     localSourceProvider.MediaPlayer.SnapshotTaken += (sender, e) =>
     {
        dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            //Not getting this log
            log.Info($"MediaPlayer.SnapshotTaken on file: {e.FileName}, {e.ToString()}");
        }));
     };      

    if (!camera1.MediaPlayer.IsPlaying())
       camera1.MediaPlayer.Play(new Uri("rtsp://admin:fake_password@192.168.11.25:554/Streaming/channels/101"));
  }
});
```

After that following code to take snapshot. `TakeSnapshot` is always returning `true` but not saving the image on the directory.:

```
public void TakeImage(string cameraName, string path)
{
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }
        var url = path + "\\" + an_unique_file_name.jpg;
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(url);
        try
        {
            VlcVedioSourceProvider vlcVedioSourceProvider = sourceProvider.GetValueOrDefault(cameraName);

            if (vlcVedioSourceProvider.MediaPlayer != null)
            {
                var isSnapshotTaken = vlcVedioSourceProvider.MediaPlayer.TakeSnapshot(fileInfo);
                //Here isSnapshotTaken is always returning true but fileInfo?.Exists is always false.
                log.Info($"isSnapshotTaken: {isSnapshotTaken}, fileExists:  {fileInfo?.Exists}");
            }
            else
            {
                log.Info($"MediaPlayer is null");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error($"Error", ex);
            throw ex;
        }        
}
```

Using following version of library:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    ....
<PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows" Version="3.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Vlc.DotNet.Wpf" Version="3.1.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This code was working fine. Suddenly it stopped working. What might be the cause and solution?